# Transitive or Intransitive

Tags: grammar

Scatter (transitive or intransitive or both)

> 1. If your drop these toys, they will scatter everywhere.
> 2. If your drop these toys, they will be scattered everywhere.

What is correct and natural here can I use it as intransitive verb?

---

> 3. If you do this to me my dreams will scatter.
> 4. If you do this to me my dreams will be scattered.

---

> 5. The toys are scattering on the floor.
> 6. The toys are getting scattered on the floor.

Comment: Have you tried consulting a dictionary? https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scatter

Comment: yes, i did but somewhere this in transitive and somewhere intransitive so in my examples what is correct? and especially in # 5 and 6 examples

Comment: Dictionaries are not where you find out about grammar. As you note, transitivity is not an inherently obvious fact about verbs. If you find that _scatter_ is sometimes transitive and sometimes intransitive, what will you learn? And where did you learn that either the active or the passive form must be incorrect, if you didn't learn which one it was?

Comment: I didn't understand your question it would be really helpful if you could answer what's the difference and which one is correct?

Comment: People and animals scatter (move off in different directions). Things or substances are scattered. Toys can't move by themselves, so they _are scattered_. (It seems an odd word to use about dreams.)

Comment: Your examples 3 & 4 are "unnatural". Dreams are metaphorically ***shattered***, not ***scattered***.

Comment: thank you kate bunting I needed that answer

Comment: FumbleFingers
thank you i got it shatter is intransitive when we taking about glass or mirror etc. when it comes to home, dreams it is transitive right? but if someone had accident what would i use his legs shattered on action or were shattered? if you had a huge accident your bones/legs could shatter or could get shattered? here the use of transitive with usually body parts is transitive or intransitive?

Answer (score 1):

The verb "*scatter*" can be used in either a transitive or an intransitive sense. So can the verb "shatter".

Example sentences 1 and 2 are both correct and natural.  Sentences 3 and 4 are at least unusual, because as Kate Bunting  points out "scatter" is not often used of dreams, although there is nothing **grammatically** wrong in doing so. Sentance 5 is odd if noit correct. "are scattering" indicates an active, ongoing process. This could perhaps be true of some sort of active, self-propelled toys. But normally one would say "are getting scattered" as in sentence 6, or perhaps "are being scattered".